# wordpress post form to self get 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-301

I have a form post to the same url it self but some how it got 301 status code when posted.
It works on my localhost, is there something i need to configure on the hosting server? The htaccess has the same content.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Did you already try to put a "/" at the end of the action url?

Comment: Found the cause, its a plugin activated in cpanel Mod_Security, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause

its a plugin activated in cpanel Mod_Security